# Update all generic Windows 10 drivers using script?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

After installing Windows 10, I have to manually update all system drivers (i.e. right-click, update etc) to download and install the Intel version from Microsoft Update. Is there not a simpler way, like a script, to simply force all drivers under a specific category within Device Manager to be updated?

Comment: Windows Update should do the job for you automatically.

Comment: It doesn't, even running the PowerShell commands alongside PSWindowsUpdate doesn't return any drivers from Microsoft Update to replace the generic ones. However if I right-click the generic one and update, it updates!